# Problem with excluding in zip from root

Tags: zip

I have a problem with excluding directories from root (/). Other directories are ok. I do not know why.

```
zip -vry1 root.zip / -x "dev/*" -x "proc/*"
```

Still includes directories /dev and /proc.

When using on non-root directory, it was ok.

```
zip -vry1 var.zip /var -x "var/www/*"
```

This excludes whole /var/www directory.

Can someone help me with this root problem? I tried "dev", "/dev/*", "/dev/", but it is still don't work.